# How does JavaScript do the type conversion for == ?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, equality

In the below code, **a != b** when compared with `==`. My initial thought is that JavaScript would use the same conversion for parseFloat as it would with `==`. Can anyone explain what actually happens as I'm a little confused by this. **b = 129** when parsed, so it appears parseFloat will parse up to the first non-numeric character.

```
var a = '129t3.98';
var b;

b = parseFloat(a);
```

[Here is the sample script fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8dF2Q/)

I was looking to put together a very simple `isNumeric()` function using this, but I want to understand it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseFloat` function, as you've noticed, will parse up to the first character that satisfies the grammar for numeric literals. [From the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.3):

> Let *numberString* be the longest prefix of *trimmedString*, which might be *trimmedString* itself, that satisfies the syntax of a *StrDecimalLiteral*.

However, the [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) (that's what `==` does) does not follow the same rules:

> If Type(*x*) is String and Type(*y*) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(*x*) == *y*

And here's what the internal [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) operation has to say:

> If the grammar cannot interpret the String as an expansion of *StringNumericLiteral*, then the result of ToNumber is NaN.

So when you attempt to compare your string with the number resulting from parsing it, you're actually comparing the number `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are giving a=b, then the value of b goes to a, without any conversion.

When you are assigning the value as a=parseFloat(b), if b is of type string then a will be of type int.

but if a= b is assigned , then a & b are both same types.

```
if,2->int, '2' -> string 
2=='2'   (true)
2 === '2' (false)
```

by observing above conversions u can handler ur code accordingly.